# Windows and MAC OS TCP communication between two applications (MATLAB or openFrameworks)

Tags: matlab, tcp, openframeworks

I have been trying communicating between two applications, which is from Matlab to Matlab or openFrameworks (ver. 0.84) to Matlab (ver. 2012). One big difference is that one application is installed in Windows OS Windows7 and other is in Mac OS Yosemite.

TCP connection of Matlab and openFrameworks is so simple and I could made connection when both applications was in the same OS. However, when it comes to windows and mac communication, TCP was failed. Are there any regulations of different OS communication?

If you have any solution and reason, please tell me. It will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

========== additional ============

Matlab

```
t = tcpip('192.168.10.1',11999,'NetworkRole', 'server');
fopen(t);
```

openFrameworks

```
ofxTCPClient tcp;
isConnected = tcp.setup("192.168.10.2",11999);
```

Both computers' IP address was manually input.

Comment: What fails? What error message do you get?

Comment: Error message was not given. They were waiting for the connections forever. This is not happening  when it comes to the connection between applications in the same OS.  I am very wondering why.

Comment: Probably a firewall is blocking it. Please add the code to your question, "waiting forever" is something you expect only on the server/receiving side, the client/sender should run into a timeout.

Comment: I am sorry for late reply. The firewall was turned off in the both computers. Yes. The client side ran into a timeout. IP address, port, default gateway to fill in were correct too.